# GLPaint with white background

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying draw on a white background by reverse engineering GLPaint. I've gone through every combination of kSaturation, kLuminosity and glBlendFunc, AND just about every combination I can think of for brush texture (black on white, white on black, white on trans, alias/no alias, etc), but haven't stumbled upon the desired effect.

The best I've been able to achieve is with a white-on-trans circle, with glBlendFunc (GL_ SRC_ ALPHA, GL_ ONE_ MINUS_ SRC_ ALPHA), but this still gives me a dull colour, and the semi-trans outer bits are interpreted as black (i.e. dull green with black edges, instead of vibrant green with transparent edges). It's as though it still assumes I'm on a black background.

Any advice?

[image]
<sub>(source: [straandlooper.com](http://www.straandlooper.com/GLPaint.png))</sub>

Comment: You may need to play also with glTexEnv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,...). Could you post also texture setup code? What is texture format? Alpha only or opaque texture?

Comment: Hi Kevin, were you able to figure this out?  I am stuck on the same problem, can't get rid of the black outline around the color....

Comment: Bump -- I am trying to do the same thing. Any progress?

Comment: Anyone had any luck with this?  I'm also stuck, had no idea it would turn into such a huge issue  :P

Comment: Nothing. I just binned the whole thing and went to work on something else. Sorry, you're going to have to find someone smarter than me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want for it to work on White:
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Then use a white 'Particle.png' circle that feathers out to transparency (your 'best' example).

This should give in the desired result.

Comment: This didn't work for me, just by changing the blend function, and leaving everything else the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, glEnable(GL_BLEND) is in there.
I've basically started with GLPaint and changed the background to white and the rest of the code is the same. I have to assume that since GLPaint was made with black background, there's some bit of code that is set to blend ideally to black, and I don't know which switch to flip (or, indeed, what switches can be flipped. Heck, what switches even exist).

Here's what's there by default. Lemme know if you see anything awry...

glDisable(GL_DITHER)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE _2D)

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX _ARRAY)

glEnable(GL_BLEND)

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC _ALPHA, GL_ONE _MINUS _SRC _ALPHA)

glEnable(GL_POINT _SPRITE _OES)

glEnable(GL_COLOR _MATERIAL)

I don't mind telling you, I haven't a clue what any of that is.
-kev.